# Код-ревью: поиск текста в текстовых файлах и вывод результата в виде дерева

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность, инспекция-кода

Выполнял тестовое задание на вакансию джуна. Программа представляет собой поиск. Вводятся критерии поиска: исходный каталог, имя файла, текст. Вывод результата осуществляется с помощью элемента treeView в виде дерева. Официальная версия провала, что не появляется таймер с начала поиска(я не доглядел это требование). Но я предполагаю на 99%, что мой код их полностью не устроил. Также я бы хотел добавить этот код в свое резюме и поэтому прошу Вас сделать код-ревью и помочь мне разобраться с моими ошибка.

Задание:

Программа для поиска файлов по заданным критериям

Критерии:
Стартовая директория (с которой начинается поиск)
Шаблон имени файла
Текст, содержащийся в файле

Введенные критерии не должны потеряться при перезапуске программы

Во время поиска нужно отображать какой файл обрабатывается в данный момент, количество обработанных файлов и прошедшее время.
Все найденные файлы отображать в виде дерева (как в левой части проводника)
Найденные файлы должны обновляться в реальном времени
Поиск нужно уметь остановить в любой момент и затем либо продолжить, либо начать новый

Класс, который ищет файлы:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestApp
{
    class FileHandler
    {
        public string Dir { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string FileText { get; set; }

        private int countOfScannedFiles = 0;

        private void Find(string pathDir, TextBox textBox, TreeView treeView, ManualResetEvent manualEvent)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dirInf;
            try
            {
                manualEvent.WaitOne(); 

                dirInf = new DirectoryInfo(pathDir);
                DirectoryInfo[] w = dirInf.GetDirectories();

                foreach (var item in w)
                {
                    if (item.Attributes.Equals(FileAttributes.System | FileAttributes.Hidden | FileAttributes.Directory))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    Find(item.FullName, textBox, treeView, manualEvent);
                }

                FindFile(dirInf, textBox, treeView, manualEvent);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        private void FindFile(DirectoryInfo dir, TextBox textBox, TreeView treeView, ManualResetEvent manualEvent)
        {
            string[] arrFile = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir.FullName).ToArray();

            for (int n = 0; n < arrFile.Length; n++)
            {
                manualEvent.WaitOne();

                string fName = Path.GetFileName(arrFile[n]);

                Form1.SetText(textBox, String.Format("Проверяется файл: {0}\r\nВсего проверенно файлов: {1}\r\n", fName, countOfScannedFiles));

                if (fName.Contains(FileName))
                {
                    if (FindFileText(arrFile[n], manualEvent))
                    {
                        Form1.BuildTree(treeView, arrFile[n]);
                    }
                }

                countOfScannedFiles++;
            }
        }

        public bool FindFileText(string file, ManualResetEvent manualEvent)
        {
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file, Encoding.Default))
                {
                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        manualEvent.WaitOne();
                        string str = reader.ReadLine();

                        if (str.ToLower().Contains(FileText.ToLower()))
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public void StartFind(CancellationToken token, TextBox textBox, TreeView treeView, ManualResetEvent manualEvent)
        {
            if (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                countOfScannedFiles = 0;
                Find(Dir, textBox, treeView, manualEvent);
            }

            Form1.SetText(textBox, new StringBuilder(textBox.Text).AppendLine("Поиск завершен").ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Форма:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly FileHandler data = new FileHandler();
        private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;
        private ManualResetEvent manualEvent;

        private bool pause = false;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GetOldParams();
        }

        private void ButtonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (CheckParams())
            {
                InitializeParams();
                treeViewResult.Nodes.Clear();

                buttonPause.Enabled = true;
                buttonStop.Enabled = true;

                cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                manualEvent = new ManualResetEvent(true);

                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => data.StartFind(cancellationTokenSource.Token, textBoxStatus, treeViewResult, manualEvent)
                                          , TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        private void ButtonStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (manualEvent != null)
            {
                manualEvent.Reset();

                buttonPause.Enabled = false;
                buttonPause.Text = "Pause";
                buttonStop.Enabled = false;

                pause = false;

                cancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
            }
        }

        private void ButtonPause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!pause)
            {
                manualEvent.Reset();
                pause = true;
                buttonPause.Text = "Resume";
            }
            else
            {
                manualEvent.Set();
                pause = false;
                buttonPause.Text = "Pause";
            }
        }

        private void InitializeParams()
        {
            data.Dir = textBoxDir.Text;
            data.FileName = textBoxFileName.Text;
            data.FileText = textBoxFileText.Text;

            Properties.Settings.Default.dirOld = textBoxDir.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.fileNameOld = textBoxFileName.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.fileTextOld = textBoxFileText.Text;

            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

            pause = false;
        }

        private void GetOldParams()
        {
            textBoxDir.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.dirOld;
            textBoxFileName.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.fileNameOld;
            textBoxFileText.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.fileTextOld;
        }

        private bool CheckParams()
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            bool check = true;

            if (!Regex.IsMatch(textBoxDir.Text, @"^.:\w*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                builder.AppendLine("Дирректория указана некоректно.");
                check = false;
            }

            if (textBoxFileName.Text.Equals(""))
            {
                builder.AppendLine("Имя файла указано не корректно.");
                check = false;
            }

            if (textBoxFileText.Text.Equals(""))
            {
                builder.AppendLine("Текст, содержащийся в файле, не указан.");
                check = false;
            }

            textBoxStatus.Text = builder.ToString();
            return check;
        }

        private delegate void TextBoxDelegate(TextBox Info, string Text);
        public static void SetText(TextBox textBox, string text)
        {
            if (textBox.InvokeRequired)
            {
                TextBoxDelegate tbDelegate = new TextBoxDelegate(SetText);
                textBox.Invoke(tbDelegate, new object[] { textBox, text });
            }
            else
            {
                textBox.Text = text;
            }
        }

        private delegate void TreeViewDelegate(TreeView Info, string Text);
        public static void BuildTree(TreeView treeView, string path)
        {
            if (treeView.InvokeRequired)
            {
                TreeViewDelegate tvDelegate = new TreeViewDelegate(BuildTree);
                treeView.Invoke(tvDelegate, new object[] { treeView, path });
            }
            else
            {
                var childs = treeView.Nodes;
                foreach (var part in path.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar))
                {
                    childs = FindOrCreateNode(childs, part).Nodes;
                }
            }
        }

        private static TreeNode FindOrCreateNode(TreeNodeCollection coll, string name)
        {
            var found = coll.Find(name.ToLower(), false);
            if (found.Length > 0) return found[0];
            return coll.Add(name.ToLower(), name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В качестве параметров в методы поиска передаются контролы. Зачем? Когда вам нужны только значения из них. Тоже самое касается и кода заполнения TreeView: поиск должен возвращать коллекцию данных, а заполнение TreeView вынести в отдельный метод формы, в идеале в кастомный биндинг, но это уже высший пилотаж т.к. обычного биндинга у штатного TreeView не предусмотрено.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Комментарии по коду:

1. Вы просите оценить вашу реализацию и её соотвестие тестовому заданию, но не приводите само тестовое задание. То есть код есть, а постановки задачи нет
2. Названия перменных не отражают ничего.

> CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource, ManualResetEvent manualEvent,

давайте переменным осмысленные названия (см Clean code, Framework design guidlines)

3. Названия ваших типов никак не соответсвуют их назначению,

> Form1, FileHandler

4. Вместо разделения ответственностей, у вас лапша кода в главной форме. Смотри S в SOLID
5. Сервисные классы, предназначенные для работы с файлами, вдруг почему то обладают знаниями о юзер интерфейсе

> public void StartFind(CancellationToken token, TextBox textBox, TreeView treeView, ManualResetEvent manualEvent)

смотри также S в SOLID (а лучше весь SOLID почитай)

6. Названия методов не соотвествуют тому, что они делают, например `GetOldParams();` то есть метод `ПолучитьСтарыеПараметры` ничего не получает и не возвращает, а вместо этого меняет состояние формы, что нелогично
7. Вы прямо в форму ввинтили флаги типа private bool pause = false;, что делает ваш код не переиспользуемым. Я бы посоветовал оформить UserControl вместо этого.
8. Знай API своего фреймворка, чтобы проверить путь на валидность, можно испольщовать `Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars` и `Path.GetInvalidPathChars`, чтобы проверить папку на существование, есть `Directory.Exists`

Вот это

> using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file, Encoding.Default))

можно заменить на

> File.ReadLines(...)

9. Не глуши эксепшоны просто так, хотя бы логгируй их или показывай юзеру, что то то пошло не так catch (Exception) { return false; }
10. Не раскрывай подробности импементации своего класса

    > public string FileName { get; set; }

подобные вещи должны быть приватными. См Инкапсуляция

11. Зачем вам вообще все эти поля `cancellationTokenSource, pause` на форме? Вы не можете сделать методы Pause и Stop прямо в классе FileHandler?
12. Публичные методы, которые должны быть приватными public bool FindFileText(string file, ManualResetEvent manualEvent)

Вот пример того, с чего можно было бы начать

```
public class FileSearcher
{
    private Stack<string> _folders = new Stack<string>();
    private Stack<string> _files = new Stack<string>(); 
    private HashSet<string> _result = new HashSet<string>();

    private string _textToSearch;
    private volatile bool pause = false;
    private int checkedFilesCount = 0;

    public void Start(){
        pause = false;
        Task.Run(()=>SearchLoop());
    }

    public void Pause(){
        pause = true;
    }

    private void SearchLoop(){
        while(!pause && PerformSearchStep());
    }

    private bool PerformSearchStep()
    {   
        if (_files.Count > 0)
        {
            var file = _files.Pop();
            checkedFilesCount++;
            var isMatched = CheckFile(file, _textToSearch);
            if (isMatched)          
                _result.Add(file);              
            FileSearchProgressEventInvocation(checkedFilesCount, file, isMatched);          
            return true;
        }       
        else if (_folders.Count > 0){           
            var folder = _folders.Pop();

            if (Directory.Exists(folder)){
                var innerFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(folder);
                var files = Directory.GetFiles(folder);             
                foreach(var innerFolder in innerFolders) _folders.Push(innerFolder);
                foreach(var innerfile in files) _files.Push(innerfile);
            }           
            return true;
        }   

        return false;
    }

    private static bool CheckFile(string filePath, string searchText)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(filePath)) return false;
        return File.ReadLines(filePath).Any(line => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) && line.Contains(searchText));
    }

    public FileSearcher(string path, string textToSearch)
    {       
        _textToSearch = textToSearch;
        _folders.Push(path);
    }   

    public event EventHandler<FileSearchProgressEventArgs> FileSearchProgressEvent;
    private void FileSearchProgressEventInvocation(int currentFileIndex, string currentFileName, bool isMatched){
        FileSearchProgressEvent?.Invoke(this, new FileSearchProgressEventArgs(currentFileIndex, currentFileName, isMatched));
    }

    public class FileSearchProgressEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public int CurrentFileIndex{get;private set;}
        public string CurrentFileName{get;private set;}
        public bool IsMatched{get;private set;}

        public FileSearchProgressEventArgs(int currentFileIndex, string currentFileName, bool isMatched)
        {
            CurrentFileIndex = currentFileIndex;
            CurrentFileName = currentFileName;
            IsMatched = isMatched;
        }
    }   
}
```

У этого класса нет зависимостей от UI или многопоточности, он не блокирует в простое никакой поток, он обладает простым и понятным API и может быть использован даже в консольном приложении.

```
var searcher = new FileSearcher("path to dir", "text to search");
searcher.FileSearchProgressEvent += 
    (sender, args) => 
      Console.WriteLine($"{args.CurrentFileIndex}|{args.IsMatched}: {args.CurrentFileName}");

searcher.Start();

// .....

searcher.Pause();
```

Comment: здравствуйте! Спасибо большое за подробный анализ. Добавил саму задачу. Буду разбираться...